# How to improve my search view to search for every word in that item?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, search, searchview

I would like to know if there is a way to improve search view like this.
For Example if i have a listview with items like this : "Ice cream with banana and chocolate ", "Apple juice", "Coffe ", "Big Cheesburger". And i type this in search : ,, banana chocolate ,, the result of search is Ice cream with banana and chocolate. I hope u understood my example, in my opinion it was the simplest way to explain. Please answer me , I look forward to your reply. Here is my code

```
public class recepies extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    String[] recepies={"Čili Piletina\n"+ " pileće belo meso \n"+" crvena paprika \n"+" čili papričica \n"+" crveni pasulj \n"+" kukuruzni šećer \n"+" paradajz pelat\n"+" kisela pavlaka\n"+ " biljni začin\n "+ " biber\n "+" ulje ",
            "Prženija sa svinjskim butom\n" +" svinjski but"+" kiseli krastavčići , kisala paprika,tucana paprika,biljni začin,biber,origano ulje, so, lovorov list",
            "Peketići od integralnih palačinki\n" + "integralno brašno ,voda, soda bikarbona, ulje, kisela pavlaka, krastavac, paradajz, kikiriki",
            "Ćufte od mesa i karfiola (hrono recept)\n" + "mleveno meso, karfiol, crni luk, beli luk, peršun, belance, so, biber, kurkuma, ulje, tikvice, sok od paradajza",
            "Paprika punjena rižom i piletinom\n" +"paprika babura,belo meso,šargarepa,crni luk,pirinač,paradajz,sok od paradajza,biljnog začina,so,biber, kari,peršun, maslinovo ulje,",
            "Piletina u sosu od nara\n" +"belo meso,\n" + "soja sos,\n" + "biber,\n" + "kurkuma,\n" + "luk,\n" + "soka od nara,\n" + "đumbir,\n" + "pirinač,\n" + "čili ili tabasko sos,\n" + "bbq ili roštilj sos,"
    };


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recepies);
        registerClickCallback();
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,recepies);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    private void registerClickCallback(){
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                    TextView textView= (TextView) viewClicked;
                    if(position==0){
                        goToRecepie1();
                    }else if(position==1){
                        goToRecepie2();
                    }else if(position==2){
                        goToRecepie3();
                    }else if(position==3){
                        goToRecepie4();
                    }else if(position==4){
                        goToRecepie5();
                    }else if(position==5){
                        goToRecepie6();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToRecepie6() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie6.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToRecepie5() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie5.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToRecepie4() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie4.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToRecepie3() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie3.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToRecepie2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie2.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToRecepie1() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recepie1.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to did that.
Segment every item. For example, "Ice cream with banana and chocolate" can be segmented as "ice cream", "cream with", "with banana", "ice with chocolate" and so on. Then you can search every "word" you want.
Actually, wo do that thing at server instead of client. You can get more information about it throw [Lucence](https://lucene.apache.org).

Comment: Thanks sir , but maybe I explained bad, if in 1 item i have ,, sauce , ketchup, cheese, meat,, and i type ketchup cheese it won't pop out as a search result. And it is too much to write in every order as you explained like : cheese,meat , ketchup , sauce,, and than again ,, cheese , ketchup,sauce,,..